# Replace array with another array in C

Tags: objective-c, c, arrays

Out of pure curiosity, I started playing with array's in ways that I have never used before. I tried making a data structure array, and set it equal to another:

```
typedef struct _test {
   float value;
} test;
```

Simple enough `struct`, so I tried this:

```
test struct1[10];
test struct2[20];
struct1 = struct2;
```

I didn't think this would work, and it didn't even compile. But, this interests me a lot. Is it possible to take an array of 10 and increase the size to 20, while copying the data?

**Objective-C**

I am actually doing this with Objective-C, so I'd like to hear from the Objective-C people as well. I want to see if it is possible to change the size of `struct1` in this file.

```
@interface Object : NSObject {
    test struct1;
}
```

**Remember:** This is only out of curiosity, so everything is open to discussion.

Answer (score 4):

Something else that is not exactly pertinent to your question but is interesting nonetheless, is that although arrays cannot be assigned to, structs containing arrays *can* be assigned to:

```
struct test
{
    float someArray[100];
};


struct test s1 = { /* initialise with some data*/ };
struct test s2 = { /* initialise with some other data */ };

s1 = s2; /* s1's array now contains contents of s2's array */
```

This also makes it possible to return fixed-length arrays of data from functions (since returning plain arrays is not allowed):

```
struct test FunctionThatGenerates100Floats(void)
{
    struct test result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        result.someArray[i] = randomfloat();

    return result;
}
```

Comment: That is another superb approach to using structs. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this in C with static arrays, but you can do it with dynamically allocated arrays. E.g.,

```
float *struct1, *struct2, *struct3;
if(!(struct1 = malloc(10 * sizeof(float))) { 
  // there was an error, handle it here
}
if(!(struct2 = realloc(struct1, 20 * sizeof(float))) {
  // there was an error, handle it here
  // struct1 will still be valid
}
if(!(struct3 = reallocf(struct2, 40 * sizeof(float))) {
  // there was an error, handle it here
  // struct2 has been free'd
}
```

Comment: Quite interesting. If tried this way, wouldn't it then be possible to to make a nearly limitless sized array based on other variables? For intense, if I made `void setSize(int size)`, it could be placed at the maximum size (whatever that is)z

Comment: Good question: you need to check that malloc and realloc could actually alloc the amount of space you asked for -- they return NULL is there was an error. I've edited the above post to reflect this.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I can see how this could help in the future.

Comment: Another small point to note: if realloc fails to reallocate the array, the input pointer (in this case, struct1) is still valid. The reallocf variant will free the input pointer if the allocation fails.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, arrays allocated like that are static, and can not be resized. You have to use pointers (allocating the array with `malloc` or `calloc`) to have a resizable array, and then you can use `realloc`. You must use `free` to get rid of it (else you'll leak memory). In C99, your array size can be calculated at runtime when its allocated (in C89, its size had to be calculated at compile time), but can't be changed after allocation. In C++, you should use `std::vector`. I suspect Objective-C has something like C++'s vector.

But if you want to copy data between one array and another in C, use `memcpy`:

```
/* void *memcpy(void *dest, const void *src, size_t n)
   note that the arrays must not overlap; use memmove if they do */
memcpy(&struct1, &struct2, sizeof(struct1));
```

That'll only copy the first ten elements, of course, since struct1 is only ten elements long. You could copy the last ten (for example) by changing `&struct2` to `struct2+10` or `&(struct2[10])`. In C, of course, not running off the end of the array is your responsibility: `memcpy` does not check.

You can also you the obvious for loop, but memcpy will often be faster (and should never be slower). This is because the compiler can take advantage of every trick it knows (e.g., it may know how to copy your data 16 bytes at a time, even if each element is only 1 byte wide)

Comment: Interesting approach. I have never heard of this before, but it makes a lot of sense to me. I am assuming that the sizeof() should not just be a numeric constant?

Comment: @Justin: `sizeof` is effectively a numeric constant, it just lets the compiler do the math for you. It also knows how the compiler decided to lay out your data (e.g., any padding it may have added).

Comment: I did not know that. That is a very nice way to do this.

Comment: Objective-C *the language* doesn't have a resizable array type, but the Foundation Kit framework (which is what most Objective-C programmers use) has `NSMutableArray`.

Answer (score 1):

In C, I believe that's a good place to use the realloc function. However, it will only work with dynamically allocated arrays. There's no way to change the memory allocated to `struct1` by the declaration `test struct1[10];`.

Comment: realloc works on dynamically allocated pointers, not on arrays (which are allocated by the compiler).

Comment: Um, yes. I believe that's what I said.

Comment: So if I used the `malloc` function, `realloc` would be a good option?

Comment: @Justin - Yes. Take a look at the [man page for realloc](http://linux.die.net/man/3/realloc) for how to use it. (Don't forget to `free` the memory at the end.)

Answer (score 1):

In C arrays are constants, you can't change their value (that is, their address) at all, and you can't resize them.

Comment: That may be the case, but it is still interesting to think about it, and find a way around that issue.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly if you declare your array with a fixed size, `test struct1[10]` then it cannot be resized. What you need to do is to declare it as a pointer:

```
test *struct1;
```

Then you must use `malloc` to allocate the array and can use `realloc` to resize it whilst preserving the contents of the original array.

```
struct1 = malloc(10*sizeof(*struct1));
//initialize struct1 ...
test *struct2 = realloc(struct1, 20*sizeof(*struct1));
```

Comment: It is important to note that most people then put `free()` in there. Would that still be a good idea if one wanted to use the array variable later?

Comment: What would you free? You presumably want to use struct2. Obviously you can't use something after free.

Comment: Good point, but I am just sating that if, for instance, `struct2` was only used as a way to increase the size of `struct1`, it should be freed. Am I correct, or is that the explanation for a lot errors?

Comment: No you've got that wrong. When realloc succeeds, struct1 is invalid and you can only refer to struct2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Objective C, you know you can just use NSMutableArray, which automatically does the realloc trick to reallocate itself to store however many objects you put in it, up the limit of your memory.

But you're trying to do this with struct? What would that even mean? Suppose you increase the amount of memory available to struct1 in Object. It's still a struct with one member, and doesn't do anything more.

Is the idea to make Object be able to contain an expanded struct?

```
typedef struct _test2 {
    float value;
    NSObject *reference;
} test2;
```

But then you still can't access `reference` normally, because it's not a known part of Object.

```
Object *object2;
...
NSLog(@"%@", object2.struct1.reference); // does not compile
```

If you knew you had one of your modified objects, you could do

```
Object *object2;
...
NSLog(@"%@", ((test2)(object2.struct1)).reference);
```

And also you could still presumably pass object2 to anything that expects an Object. It only has any chance of working if struct1 is the last member of Object, and don't mess with subclassing Object either.

Some variety of realloc trick might then work, but I don't think realloc in particular, because that's intended to be used on objects that are allocated with malloc, and the details of what C function is used to allocate objects in not exposed in Objective C, so you shouldn't assume it's malloc. If you override `alloc` then you might be able to make sure malloc is used.

Also you have to watch out for the fact that it's common in Objective C for more than one pointer to an object to exist. realloc might move an object, which won't be semantically correct unless you correct all the pointers.

Comment: Another interesting approach. I am not sure that you can put an object in a struct, but I'll check it out. I am using a struct so I can do something like `struct1.value = 1` instead of `[[Object struct1] setValue:1]`. It is sooo much better to look at and edit.

Comment: Yes, you can put a _pointer_ to an object in a struct, but that was just an example.

Comment: I think you need to get more familiar with Objective C syntax. You don't need to do anything that verbose to set an object's field. From within the object you can just say `value = 1`. Outside the object you can't do `struct1.value = 1` either. But you can set up a @property and then you can access value by dot notation. In any case I don't understand what a _resizable_ struct has to do with that purpose. What you are trying to do can only be done so hackishly that it's definitely not worth it for the purpose of making your code prettier. In any case Objective C supports pretty code already.

Comment: Still, I have already said that I am doing this out of curiosity. By the way, you _can_ actually do that from outside the object, you just have to be creative. In addition to all of this, the actual struct is in use in _many_ different classes, so it makes sense to have slightly more efficient, small way to store normal `floats` than using an `NSValue`, `NSNumber`, or formatted `NSString` for performance reasons. Still, your logic is undeniable.

Comment: You're not required to use NSValue or NSNumber in Objective C. You can have a direct float member of an object. Just `@interface Object : NSObject { float value; }`

Comment: But if I want an array, I will need to use one of those to store it.

Comment: So, is that your real purpose? You want to have a dynamically-sized array of floats without using NSNumber? If so you might try std::vector<float> from C++ (which is allowed in Objective C).

Comment: Like I said, I have no purpose for this yet. I am just very curious, and I want to get the most out of my code.